# How to get all products with attribute data in custom created class

Tags: magento2, product-collection, programmatically

I'm pretty new to Magento, and I are trying to create a module for it, but I'm a little stock now because I'm trying to get all products out there are created in the store there are enabled.

I'm working on a custom central class for my module so I can call my functions on cross for CLI, Crontabs where else I need it.

And what I need its called just a new product class and then get products data out like this.

```
use SmartPack\Framework\Product;

$products = new Product();
print_r($products->getProducts());
```

And the class I start working on its like this

```
<?php
namespace CustomClass\Framework;

class Product
{
    function getProducts()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Mabey I miss understand how its working on Magento and how to speak with the framework, so hope on a little help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm search a lot and found  this solution, and its working as I need. The response from Dhiren I did not found use full based on I need my data into a CLI command.

```
<?php

namespace SmartPack\Framework;

class Product
{
    function getProducts()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $this->productCollection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

        $products = $this->productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                'status',
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED
            )
            ->getData();

        return $products;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code to get enable product collection.

```
class Yourclass extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{   
    /*Product collection variable*/ 
    protected $_productCollection;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollection,       
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollection= $productCollection;    
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    public function getProductCollection()
    {

        $collection = $this->_productCollection->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);

        return $collection;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If I use your sample, its give me this error return ( PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function SmartPack\Framework\Product::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/project/app/code/SmartPack/WMS/Console/Command/ProductSync.php on line 54 and at least 2 expected in /var/www/project/app/code/SmartPack/Framework/Product.php:10 )

So the problem is when I try call this function inside a CLI code its get broken.

Comment: It clear tell that in your constructor you not pass the argument where in above answer I pass 2 argument there.

Comment: Yes, I know the problem is its not working, the way I found its not the same as yours, but almost, did not know the different for sure, look my replay. Mabey you can explain why my code working and what you show me here did not working as expect.